# Opening a Word document at a particular bookmark

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, ms-word

Using MVC 5 Razor Views.
I currently have a link to open a document that sits on the server in my about view as follows........

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/content/docs/My Doc - Basic Training.docx")">Basic Training <img src="~/Content/Images/Word.jpg" height="24" width="24" /></a>
```

What I'd like is to be able to have a link to open this document at a particluar bookmark.

From what I have read so far, it would seem that the bookmark is specified after a # symbol.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work and the document just opens from the start.

I've tried opening via an action using the #' notation as werll, but as yet, no joy.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(@"~\Content\My Doc - Basic Training.docx"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
return File(fs, "My Doc - Basic Training.docx");
```

I've simply been appending #BoomarkName to the filename.  No joy as of yet.

Is it possible?
If so could someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just seems to work with `#bookmark_name`, as explained in [How to create a hyperlink from an HTML page to a bookmark in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310520).

So:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/content/docs/My Doc - Basic Training.docx#your_bookmark")">Basic Training <img src="~/Content/Images/Word.jpg" height="24" width="24" /></a>
```

Comment: I will get back to this later but I had tried this with no joy.
I will attempt it again and put my results here..............

Hmmm, I'm just wonering (and it would seem that I didn't) if I deployed my doc uopdated with the bookmarks to the actual server......

Comment: Nope - I get the Save or Open dialog.
I select open.......The doc opens from the start.

Via the Insert menu I click, Bookmark which shows me my list of bookmarks, I can select one and select GoTo which works.  So I know the right doc is there on the server.

However, it was meant to go straight to that bookmark upon opening.....so no, that method does not work.